# Firebase Error: code: "auth/user-not-found"

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I have a user which currently exists in Firebase, however I have written JS code to `getUser` which does not run.

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

module.exports = function(req, res) {
  const UID = String(req.body.uid);
  const YOB = String(req.body.YOB);
  const gender = String(req.body.gender);
  const salary = String(req.body.salary);
  const hoursWorked = String(req.body.hoursWorked);

  admin.auth().getUser(UID)
    .then(userRecord => {
      admin.database().ref('users/' + UID)
        .update({
            YOB: YOB,
            gender: gender,
            salary: salary,
            hoursWorked: hoursWorked
          },
          () => {
            res.send({
              success: true
            });
          });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.status(422).send({
        error: err
      });
    });
}
```

I'm using Postman to send the request with JSON data as follows:

```
{
  "UID": "JjeSOpY159Pv0qonNNp200qu7wY2",
  "YOB": "1985",
  "gender": "Female",
  "salary": "20.2",
  "hoursWorked": "8"
}
```

Firebase:

[image: firebase dashboard]

I know that I have a stable connection to firebase because I can create users using the following code:

```
    const admin = require('firebase-admin');

    module.exports = function(req, res) {
        admin.auth().createUser({})
            .then(user => res.send(user))
            .catch(err => res.status(422).send({ error: err}));
    }
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to why that error could occur?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/errors

Comment: Make sure the correct UID get passed into the `getUser()` method. Some additional logging should help.

Comment: Hi @Christopher, did you find the reason/solution for this? I met the same issue

Comment: @HoangTrinh No I never did